# Where in the world does blue eyed whites originate from?

Tags: human-biology, human-genetics, human-eye

I know that there were no blue eyed people until ~6000 years ago due to a mutation and all blue eyed people have a single common anchestor.

But where in the world does it originate? I assume it originates from somewhere in Europe but is it known more specifically where like Scandinavia, Eastern Europe, and so on or is it impossible to know?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_color#Blue) has your answer already !

Comment: @Dexter Exactly where is the answer to the "*Where in the world...*" question?

Comment: @fileunderwater Reference no [46](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v507/n7491/full/nature12960.html)

Comment: @Dexter How about elaborating on that instead of posting an uninformative link to a wikipedia page. I also dont see how the finding of a blue eyed human in Spain from 5000BC is answering the question of the origin of blue eyes. Are there other 5000BC hunter-gatherers from other parts of Europe with sequenced genomes (where the allele wasn't found) used as comparisons? Otherwise it is only showing that the allele is more than 7000y old and occuring in Spain at that time.

Comment: @fileunderwater I agree I didn't elaborate. Sorry about that. However that doesn't mean I posted uninformative link. Link suggests 7000 y old skeleton with homozygous HERC2–OCA2 locus which is strongly associated with blue eyes.  In fact [first link](https://occupycorporatism.com/blue-eyes-originated-10000-years-ago-in-the-black-sea-region/) from google search gave me origin of blue eyes in Black Sea region (and guess which gene was correlated ? **OCA2**.

Comment: @Dexter Sorry about the wording "uninformative link" - I meant that the link text was uninformative, not necessarily the content. Your last link is the first one that seems to provide an answer to the question though. You should post it as an actual answer instead.